Can spring constant change by twisting or unwinding spring?
I am trying to study analytically the behaviour twisting springs and I noticed that if I consider mass and shape of spring the winding and unwinding of spring affects it's mass distribution and was wondering if it changes the spring constant. If it is true, are the effects significant or I can neglect them for large springs?

sounds like an engineering question to me

Reminds me of an old joke: Q: "Why are most models in physics linear ?" A: "Because if it's not linear it's engineering not physics".

Yes, deep down all real springs are non-linear. As you load up a spring the shape changes in various ways (winding, expansion, radial growth etc) and thus geometric non-linearities are introduced.
At some limit, springs will have clashing coils which increase the stiffness coefficient by an order of magnitude. This is called "going solid" in spring speak.
And for dynamics springs, there are stress waves going up and down the spring change also change the apparent mass of the spring, and can cause the coil clashing way before the static limit for "going solid".
